# How can I make sure that wlan0: becomes ready before it tries to get an ip from DHCP on boot?

Tags: boot, wifi, dhcp

As the title states my RaspberryPi's WiFi adapter (Edimax EW-7811UN (8192CU)) is in most cases (approx 70% of the time) not ready when it tries to get an IP using DHCP on boot. It happens often that the link becomes ready after the DHCP client tried to get an IP Address. In most cases it becomes ready when I'm at the login prompt. I've already deactivated the powersaver by creating the following file with the following contents:

> /etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf
>
> options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0

I've already checked on Realtek's site and it looks like my version of the driver installed (came with latest raspbian image) is the latest: v4.0.2_9000

I need this to work on boot as I have something that gets mounted via fstab and then is used by a daemon.

Is there anything else I can do to make sure the device is ready when the DHCP client tries to get an IP?

Answer (score 1):

I think this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/460112/how-do-i-run-a-script-5mn-after-startup) on the superuser site will do what you need, either use the hack of setting a delay time which is crude or use the more robust and elegant

"
The right way to do it is to make your startup script run after the stuff it depends on. How you do this differs between distros.

"

edit: this will only complete when wlan0 is assigned

```
while [ -z "$(/sbin/ifconfig wlan0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 )" ]; do

  sleep 5

done

  echo "dhcp ip assigned do something";
```

Comment: Unfortunately where not talking about a startup script that I've written. Its the standard boot sequence that comes with raspbian. Even if I could find where to alter those (most likely very complicated) scripts, what would I have to add there? Whats the variable or function to check if the link is ready?

Comment: Unfortunately thats also not what I need. Your function  checks if the device has got an IP address. But before it can get an IP address the link has to "become ready". Which is what I have to check for...

Comment: I think it would help if you told us what this "link" is, so far something called the link is set before the ip so fails, then you cannot use a mounted device remotely, do you mean a vpn connection when you say "link", I think you need to take the link out of startup and put it into a cron that is only run after boot up if finished, the bash script would have to check the link/service is alive every 1 min/ 10 mins and if dead then restart the process.  I have experienced latency when uploading small files using wifi, what about a wired network connection instead

Comment: On boot, right after "Configuring network interfaces" there is a message saying "IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready". Then sometimes after that there comes another message: "IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready". Only if that second messages is displayed before trying to get an IP the DHCP client is able to get an IP for wlan0. In most cases though that message is displayed _after_ the DHCP client broadcasted the IP address request.

Comment: what driver version are you using, this page [ http://openelec.tv/forum/124-raspberry-pi/59781-2-99-1-and-edimax-wifi ] describes exact problem your having, page doesn't state which edimax wifi usb model, solution is use driver version " Problem / issue fixed with RC 2.99.2 =)  "

Comment: That post is more than 1.5 years old. Back in those days the driver was not included in the raspbian image. It is now. As mentioned above: "I've already checked on Realtek's site and it looks like my version of the driver installed (came with latest raspbian image) is the latest: v4.0.2_9000".

Answer (score 0):

As Raspbian Jessie uses `systemd`, it's better to use its capability to restart services, instead of throwing a `sleep 5` spanner into the engine. I've successfully using this for both `hostapd.service` and `isc-dhcp-server`: edit their service unit files and add:

```
RestartSec=5
Restart=on-failure
```